# Intellij Idea: Exclude target folder in play framework project

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I exclude the target folder of play framework project in Intellij Idea?

I am using `Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources` and mark target folder as excluded. but after cleaning the project (deletion of target folder) exclude removed from target folder, and all files shown duplicated when I am try to open a file, and indexing the project takes more time